# Dynamic Modal Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a table like:
[image]

When user selects Edit, it opens up a bootstrap `Modal` containing all `td` of the `tr` the Modal is launched from. What I've done so far is:

Get Row Index on Edit Click:

```
$(document).on('click', '#editNominHref', function(e) {
    var global_edit_row = $(this).closest('tr').index();
    $('#editNomiModal').modal('show');  
});
```

What I want is:

```
$('#editNomiModal').on('show.bs.modal', function ()  {
    $("#Name_feild_of_Modal").val(name_in_td_of_nth_Tr);
   // ..Similar for DOB, Relation and share%..
});
```

Question:

How do I pass the `tr` index from `Edit.click` to `Modal.show` function?

Comment: how about set a global variable to store the tr index when hit the click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can pass data directly to the modal. However, you can use `data` attributes to modify the DOM which can then be read from the `show.bs.modal` event. Something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#editNominHref', function(e) {
    $('#editNomiModal')
        .data('row-index', $(this).closest('tr').index()) 
        .modal('show');  
});

$('#editNomiModal').on('show.bs.modal', function ()  {
    var $tr = $('#myTable tr').eq($(this).data('row-index'));
    var serial = $tr.find('td:eq(0)').text();
    var name = $tr.find('td:eq(1)').text();
    // and so on...

    $("#Serial_field_of_Modal").val(serial);
    $("#Name_field_of_Modal").val(name);
    // and so on...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you open the modal can't you just clone the `<tr>` and insert into modal-content?

```
$(document).on('click', '#editNominHref', function(e) {
    var content = $(this).closest('tr').html();
    $('#editNomiModal').find('modal-content').html(content).modal('show');  
});
```

Obviously more formatting would be required.